# SQL Loader row delimiter override

Tags: csv, oracle11g, sql-loader

Is there a way to override(or disable?) row delimiter in Oracle SQL Loader? I need to load a file in a single column, but the file contains '\n', so it splits the file into multiple rows in table. Is there a way to load the whole file in table in only row? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about you replace the new line character in your control file.

Comment: I can't modify the file. I tried the `str` option when defining `infile` in my control file to override row delimiter, but then data isn't loaded at all.

Comment: I am not saying to modify the data file, I am saying use `REPLACE` while defining infile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake, missed one singlequote in STR when defining delimiter... it was `"STR '^"` instead of `"STR '^'"`